Recommended books/resources for second-order arithmetic
This question relates to books or other resources (lecture notes, etc.) for learning more about formal theories of second-order arithmetic ($\mathsf{Z_2}$, $\mathsf{ACA_0}$, etc.). Simpson’s Subsystems of Second Order Arithmetic seems to be a frequently cited work. Is it the “gold standard” on this topic? Are there other resources people would recommend?

There is a (very) introductory book for a general mathematical reader by the indefatigable John Stillwell, Reverse Mathematics: Proofs from the Inside Out (Princeton UP, 2018).
Chapter 16 of Jeremy Avigad’s Mathematical Logic and Computation (CUP, 2023) is on "Subsystems of Second-Order Arithmetic" and will make a more substantial introduction to the area.
You will certainly then want to tackle at least the overview given by the long first chapter of Simpson’s classic, which remains a must-read. You could continue some way further into Simpson’s book to fill in as much additional detail as you want.
But look too at two more recent books: first, there is David Hirschfeldt's Slicing the Truth (World Scientific, 2015). Its subtitle "On the Computable and Reverse Mathematics of Combinatorial Principles" tells you its angle.
Though you'll probably want to focus on the wider-ranging, well-structured, accessible recent book by Damir Dzhafarov and Carl Mummert, Reverse Mathematics (Springer 2022).

A note for the relevance might be apposite for the casual reader: Such subsystems of second-order arithmetic have pivotal role in reverse mathematics and extensively studied in that area.
